# How to perform grunt remote debug in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: google-chrome, intellij-idea, gruntjs, typescript, webstorm

I build and run my typescript application by Grunt and connect(grunt-contrib-connect) and livereload plugins. While grunt compile .ts files, it also generate sourcemap. My application is oppening on google chrome. How can I remotely connect by Intellij Idea to this application that was run by Grunt and oppened in Chrome for perform debug?

This post is my last hope, that it is possible. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you. I found solution.

1. First of all, I need Jet Brains extension for Chrome.
2. I need to make configure debug mode "JavaScript debug" and specify URL that grunt will run and open application.
3. Run Grunt task that build and open application in browser.
4. Run debug mode that just reload same page under debugger already.
5. Don't forget enjoy it.

Since I use typescript, ability to debug in IDE was very important.

Answer (score 1):

- create a new javascript debug run configuration
- in URL field, specify the URL of your client app (`http://localhost:9001/index.html` or whatever it looks like)
- if your local project structure doesn't exactly match the app structure on server (for example, static files are served from `<project_root>/public` folder), specify remote URL mappings (see http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Starting+a+JavaScript+debug+session#StartingaJavaScriptdebugsession-Startingadebugsessionwhenusingadifferentwebserver)

that should be enough... Start grunt, and, when the server is up and running, debug the configuration above